# React Ag-Grid update Group Rows aggregation when any of the cells are edited

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using groupRowAggNodes to define my custom aggregation logic.
Some of the columns are editable and I would like the aggregation logic to be re-applied every time the user makes a change.

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1AdV.png) to understand better. When changing Input column for Child 1 or Child 2, the

- Input column Group 1 and Group 2 are correctly updated.
- In the Output column the Child 1 and Child 2 cells are updated as well thanks to the valueGetter.
- Output column Group 1 and 2 don't get updated. --> This is what I'm trying to solve: how do I get those 2 rows to update automatically for Output Column?

This is how I define the columns:

```
    { headerName: 'Input column', 
      field: 'Input_column', 
      editable: true
    },
    { headerName: 'Output column', 
      field: 'Output_column', 
      cellRenderer:'agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer', 
      valueGetter: ' data.Input_column*2'
     }
```

This is how I define the group columns:

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
      headerName: 'Data',
      field: 'Data',
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true,
        checkbox: true,
        editable: true,     
      }
    }
```

This is the function I use for aggregation

```
groupRowAggNodes(nodes) {

    let result = {
      input_column: 0,
      output_column: 0,
      };

    let sum_input_column = 0;
    let sum_output_column = 0;

      nodes.forEach(node => {
      var data = node.group ? node.aggData : node.data;
      sum_input_column += parseInt(data.input_column);
      sum_output_column += parseInt(data.output_column);
      };

    result.input_column = sum_input_column;
    result.output_column = sum_output_column;
    return result;
    }
```

then in the render:

```
groupRowAggNodes = {this.groupRowAggNodes}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by calculating result.output_column based on other columns values. This triggers the update automatically.